# XDocReport number formatting in table

Tags: docx, xdocreport

I have a template, where I have a table with column which I want to format as currency (2 decimal places). I'm using Velocity and NumberTool, which is putted in context.

I tried to use `<<$number.format("currency", $My_data)>>` in template, but as result I got empty column.

Is there some possibility to format list field in table without writing e.g. new foreach? Is some function which can be use in tempate to format field in one column?

Regards

Comment: I think you should write $number.format("currency", $My_data)

Comment: Problem isn't in this. That was only an example.
Format function in Java side gets null as parameter when My_data is a List. I want to format My_data and display it as normal List.

XDocReport in this case is looking for single Object in Context. Now I try to force him to looking for List item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it by myself.

I must just override VelocityTemplateEngine and Formatter to recognize phrases like `<<$numberTool.format($My_data)>>`, becouse default formatter was looking for field name after first '$'.

Comment: Can You provide the solution in a little more detail? I encountered the same problem.